# Sort rows of a cell array using given indexes

Tags: matlab

We are given a cell array `Ref_M` of size m x n, and a vector `IND` of length m.

`IND(i)` contains the number of non-empty cells in the `i`th row of `Ref_M`. The purpose is to organize the lines in the cell array `Ref_M` based on the value in the `IND` vector from the largest value to the smallest.

Given:

```
Ref_M = [2x2 double]    [2x2 double]    []
        [2x2 double]     []             [] 
        [2x2 double]    [2x2 double]    []
        [2x2 double]    [2x2 double]    [2x2 double]

IND = [ 2 1 2 3]
```

The result should be:

```
New_Ref_M = [2x2 double]    [2x2 double]    [2x2 double]
            [2x2 double]    [2x2 double]    []
            [2x2 double]    [2x2 double]    []
            [2x2 double]    []              []
```

Also, is there a method to organize the cell array `Ref_M` lines without using the given vector of indexes, `IND`?

Comment: I hope my edit is what you were trying to say? The original question was really difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`sort()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html).

```
[B, transform] = sort(IND, 'descend');
New_Ref_M = Ref_M(transform, :);
```

---

You can determine `IND` on your own using:

```
IND = sum(~cellfun('isempty', Ref_M), 2);
```

Comment: Excuse me but there are an error in the second line

Comment: I've also included a way to find `IND` if it isn't given.